# Xamarin Android how to get Java class name for passing into ComponentName

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I need the Java class's name in the Constructor for `Android.Content.ComponentName` as Xamarin doesn't have an overloaded constructor that takes `typeof(ClrType)` like it does for some other things.

Comment: Have you used `ComponentName.PackageName`?

Comment: It turns out it isn't namespace.  its Java class name or something.  I was programmatically get it by doing this:  ```Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(MyClass)).Name```

Comment: It shows the Namespace of your current class using `this.ComponenetName.PackageName`. Also for the class name `this.ComponentName.ClassName` I'm not sure where you want the namespace.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I was able to solve it by doing this:  `Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(MyClass)).Name`